# How to assign the same value for next 11 consecutive months based on a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
accountid   Year    Month   Value
xyz         2019    1   0
xyz         2019    2   0
xyz         2019    3   0
xyz         2019    4   1
xyz         2019    5   0
xyz         2019    6   0
xyz         2019    7   0
xyz         2019    8   0
xyz         2019    9   0
xyz         2019    10  0
xyz         2019    11  0
xyz         2019    12  0
```

As in above dataframe the value is 1 for account xyz in month 4 so the same value should assigned for the next consecutive 11 months in that year. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and show that you have [made an attempt to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For example, you could show us things that you typed into a search engine, web pages you found this way, and explain why they did not solve the problem for you. You should also make sure the problem is clear. For example, why is month 4 the one where we copy the value? How do we know how many times to copy it? What should happen in more complex cases?

Comment: next consecutive 11 months? or 7. What is you expected output?

Comment: In this case it would be 7 months as the value is 1 in Month 4 but if the value is 1 for Month 1(Jan) and year 2019 the value 0 should be replaced by 1 for the next 11 months i.e until Month 12(Dec) in 2019

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df['Value'] |= df.groupby('Year')['Value'].cumsum()
```

```
>>> df
   accountid  Year  Month  Value
0        xyz  2019      1      0
1        xyz  2019      2      0
2        xyz  2019      3      0
3        xyz  2019      4      1
4        xyz  2019      5      1
5        xyz  2019      6      1
6        xyz  2019      7      1
7        xyz  2019      8      1
8        xyz  2019      9      1
9        xyz  2019     10      1
10       xyz  2019     11      1
11       xyz  2019     12      1
```

Comment: @Anonymous. Did you have time to test the code?